# Pointer on a float matrix is considered as *uchar

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to iterare trough a `cv::Mat` with a pointer.
So I did  the following in my function:

```
template<typename Tin=uchar,typename Tout=float>
inline cv::Mat_<Tout> dct(const cv::Mat_<Tin>& oBlock) {

    cv::Mat_<Tout> oOutput(oBlock.size());
    Tout *pointeurOut= oOutput.data; 

    //...
}
```

However, I'm getting an error at the last line (`Tout *pointeurOut= oOutput.data;`).

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'uchar *' to 'float *'

Where does that come from?

Comment: Damn. I was just going to write "From the compiler."

Comment: Yours is more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is [always a `uchar*`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat).

You should use

```
oOutput.ptr<Tout>();
```

to get the `Tout` pointer to the i-th row (by default is the 0-th row, i.e. the beginning of the image)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware `data` was a `uchar*`.

Comment: It is ;D. It's a [public member of the `Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)